# How do I match bb style syntax with regular expressions?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

This is my regular expression:

```
/^\[y\](.*?)\[\/y\]/
```

This is my subject:

> youtube is here [y]2GJSVlIGmQI[/y]

but `preg_match()` doesn't match anything from my subject.

And also is there a better solution to capture the code inside the `[y] [/y]`'s?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to remove `^` char from your regex.

Comment: You should use a different delimiter than `/` so that you don’t have to escape it, and use the `/x` modifier so that you have a chance at reading the damn thing: `preg_match('@ \[ y \] ( .*? ) \[ /y \] @x', ......`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove `^` char from your regex. `^` char matches the start of a string.

```
$str = 'youtube is here [y]2GJSVlIGmQI[/y]';

preg_match('/\[y\](.*?)\[\/y\]/', $str, $arr);

// 2GJSVlIGmQI
echo $arr[1];
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering both my questions :) Very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `^` at the beginning, like this:

```
/\[y\](.*?)\[\/y\]/
```

What the `^` does is match that expression *only if it is at the start of the string*. Removing it means the expression will match the pattern anywhere in the string.

Comment: @fenerlitk No problem. Don't forget to mark this as the correct answer if you see it as such :-)

Comment: I really appreciate your answer and believe it is the correct answer as well as Buddy's answer but I chose Buddy's answer as the correct answer because 1. He answered both of my questions, and 2. He had less reputation than yours, so I wanted to be fare. I wish I could mark both answers as correct. Thanks again. :)

Comment: No worries! The most important thing here is that you get a correct one. It's my fault I didn't see your other question there.

Answer (score 0):

Use this: `/\[y\](.*?)\[\/y\]/`